# how to have acces in json object

Tags: javascript, json, api, web

i am trying to create web-page, which use APi's from Breaking bad website, AND from this website  i received data in JSON format,  and  i tried a lot, but don't understand, how i can have acces only objects which "author" is "Walter White" 
this is received data.

[{"quote_id":1,"quote":"I am not in danger, Skyler. I am the danger!","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":2,"quote":"Stay out of my territory.","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":3,"quote":"IFT","author":"Skyler White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":4,"quote":"I watched Jane die. I was there. And I watched her die. I watched her overdose and choke to death. I could have saved her. But I didn’t.","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"},{"quote_id":5,"quote":"Say my name.","author":"Walter White","series":"Breaking Bad"}]

Comment: By filtering them?  Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method here like:

```js
var data = [{quote_id:1,quote:"I am not in danger, Skyler. I am the danger!",author:"Walter White",series:"Breaking Bad"},{quote_id:2,quote:"Stay out of my territory.",author:"Walter White",series:"Breaking Bad"},{quote_id:3,quote:"IFT",author:"Skyler White",series:"Breaking Bad"},{quote_id:4,quote:"I watched Jane die. I was there. And I watched her die. I watched her overdose and choke to death. I could have saved her. But I didn’t.",author:"Walter White",series:"Breaking Bad"},{quote_id:5,quote:"Say my name.",author:"Walter White",series:"Breaking Bad"}];

var res = data.filter(d => d.author === 'Walter White')
console.log( res )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`. Note use of `toLowerCase()` for case insensitive result.

```js
const filterKey = 'walter white';
let data = [{
  "quote_id": 1,
  "quote": "I am not in danger, Skyler. I am the danger!",
  "author": "Walter White",
  "series": "Breaking Bad"
}, {
  "quote_id": 2,
  "quote": "Stay out of my territory.",
  "author": "Walter White",
  "series": "Breaking Bad"
}, {
  "quote_id": 3,
  "quote": "IFT",
  "author": "Skyler White",
  "series": "Breaking Bad"
}, {
  "quote_id": 4,
  "quote": "I watched Jane die. I was there. And I watched her die. I watched her overdose and choke to death. I could have saved her. But I didn’t.",
  "author": "Walter White",
  "series": "Breaking Bad"
}, {
  "quote_id": 5,
  "quote": "Say my name.",
  "author": "Walter White",
  "series": "Breaking Bad"
}].filter(item => item.author.trim().toLowerCase() === filterKey);

console.log(data)
```